# "to meet" vs "to meeting"

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, syntactic-analysis

Is the following sentence correct?

> I look forward to meeting you.

Here *meeting* is used after *to*. 
We were taught in school to always use the present simple tense after *to*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the sentence is correct. The words "meeting you" form a nominal phrase (that is to say, they function as a noun), and "to" is used to make that noun the indirect object of the sentence. Using the present simple tense after "to" forms the [infinitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive), which wouldn't work for this sentence.